# How to filter the values based on a value and replace it with the corresponding names

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I'm new to Jquery.
I have two dropdownlists created by a Yii Widget. Below is the code of two dropdownlists:

```
<select id="SearchForm_min_cost_select" style="display: none;">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="10 lakhs">10 lakhs</option>
<option value="20 lakhs">20 lakhs</option>
<option value="30 lakhs">30 lakhs</option>
<option value="40 lakhs">40 lakhs</option>
<option value="50 lakhs">50 lakhs</option>
<option value="60 lakhs">60 lakhs</option>
<option value="70 lakhs">70 lakhs</option>
<option value="80 lakhs">80 lakhs</option>
<option value="90 lakhs">90 lakhs</option>
<option value="1 crores">1 crores</option>
<option value="2 crores">2 crores</option>
<option value="3 crores">3 crores</option>
<option value="4 crores">4 crores</option>
<option value="5 crores">5 crores</option>
</select>
```

```
<select id="SearchForm_max_cost_select" style="display: none;">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="10 lakhs">10 lakhs</option>
<option value="20 lakhs">20 lakhs</option>
<option value="30 lakhs">30 lakhs</option>
<option value="40 lakhs">40 lakhs</option>
<option value="50 lakhs">50 lakhs</option>
<option value="60 lakhs">60 lakhs</option>
<option value="70 lakhs">70 lakhs</option>
<option value="80 lakhs">80 lakhs</option>
<option value="90 lakhs">90 lakhs</option>
<option value="1 crores">1 crores</option>
<option value="2 crores">2 crores</option>
<option value="3 crores">3 crores</option>
<option value="4 crores">4 crores</option>
<option value="5 crores">5 crores</option>
</select>
```

**OnSelect**, I call the below function `cost_change(item.value)`

```
function cost_change(price) {


    var match =  <?php echo json_encode(Yii::app()->params['match_resales']);?>;
    console.log("match",match);    
    var value=match[price];
    console.log("value",value);

      jQuery('#SearchForm_max_cost_select').html(jQuery('#SearchForm_min_cost_select').html())     
    var toKeep = jQuery('#SearchForm_max_cost_select option').filter( function( ) {
        return parseInt(this.value) > parseInt( value);       
 } );        
   console.log("to keep",toKeep);

   jQuery('#SearchForm_max_cost_select').html(toKeep);

}
```

```
'match_resales' => array('10 lakhs'=>'1000000.0','20 lakhs'=>'2000000.0','30 lakhs'=>'3000000.0','40 lakhs'=>'4000000.0','50 lakhs'=>'5000000.0','60 lakhs'=>'6000000.0','70 lakhs'=>'7000000.0','80 lakhs'=>'8000000.0','90 lakhs'=>'9000000.0','1 crores'=>'10000000.0','2 crores'=>'20000000.0','3 crores'=>'30000000.0','4 crores'=>'40000000.0','5 crores'=>'50000000.0'),
```

Now, in the above code, based on the `selected value` I encode the array of key-value pairs to a JSON array of key-value pairs, find the value corresponding to the variable price and store it in variable `value`.
In the above code, I need to manipulate the function such that it finds all options greater than value and display it in the second dropdownlist.

**EDIT**
I'm getting it correct till `value` is retrieved from JSON array. After that I want to find all values greater than `value` and display their corresponding values in the second dropdownlist

Comment: Could you create a Jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming both lists are the same:

```
// Keep a copy of the default options
var $options = $('#SearchForm_min_cost_select').children().clone();

// Within your change handler:

var index = $('#SearchForm_min_cost_select').find(':selected').index() + 1;
$('#SearchForm_max_cost_select').html($options).children(':lt('+index+')').remove();
```

disclaimer: *This could most probably be optimized for performance, however it is reasonably simple to understand.*

Comment: I need to find all values greater than the selected value of first dropdownlist and populate their corresponding names in second dropdownlist.

Comment: I had a look at your fiddle but the second dropdown should give value greater than first one and not the same as the one selected in first. Please tell me how I can do this

Comment: Just increment the index. (`index++`)

Comment: Can you please tell me where as I'm trying to understand the code still

Comment: @user3004356 - I edited the code within my answer to add `+ 1` on the end of the `index` variable definition.

Comment: <script>
`function cost_change() {
        var $options = jQuery('#SearchForm_min_cost_select').children().clone();
        console.log("options",$options);
        var index = jQuery('#SearchForm_min_cost_select').find(':selected').index()+1;
        console.log("index",index);
        jQuery('#SearchForm_max_cost_select').html($options).children(':lt('+index+')').remove();
    }
</script>` I used the above script in my application. This works fine, but it is not checking the condition if max value < min value then it should reset the value of max = min. How to do this